# How to calculate a facial point grid using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, delaunay

I'm trying to automatically draw a mesh or grid over a face, similar to the image below, to use the result in a blog post that I'm writing. However, my knowledge of computer vision is not enough to recognize which model or algorithm is behind these types of cool visualizations.

**Could someone help pointing me some link to reador or a starting point?**

[image]

Using `Python`, `OpenCV` and `dlib` the closest thing I found is something called delauny triangulation but I'm not sure if that's exactly what I'm looking for seeing the results.

Putting it in a few words what I have so far is:

1. Detect all faces on image and calculate their landmarks using `dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()` and `dlib.shape_predictor()` methods from dlib.
2. Use the method `cv2.Subdiv2D()` from OpenCV to compute a 2D subdivision based on my landmarks. In particulary I'm getting the delauny subdivision using the `getTriangleList()` method from the resulting subdivision.

The complete code is available [here](https://github.com/efviodo/dlib-face-recognition-delaunay-triangulation).

However, the result is not so attractive perhaps because the division is using triangles instead of polygons and I want to check if I can improve it!